# javascript toggle hide/show not working with several display values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to switch between two divs by toggling their visibility similar to what is described here:

[https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp](https://codepen.io/lb_kan/pen/QWNrMXL)

I have the corresponding codepen [here](https://codepen.io/lb_kan/pen/QWNrMXL)

It works perfectly fine with

```
if(displayvalue == "flex"){
...}
```

but not with

```
if(displayvalue == "flex" || "-webkit-box" || "-ms-flexbox"){
...
}
```

When debugging this code in the browser I see that in the second case the function steps inside of the if block even though I can see that displayvalue = "none" as set from the previous run.

I'm new to javascript and my second question would be why I have to use window.getComputedStyle and .getPropertyValue before the if condition. In the first link from w3schools they don't do this and their code works fine. However, when I did this short.style.display didn't have any value before being set inside the if / else blocks.

Comment: show us your attempts.

Comment: syntax is wrong, try this `if (['flex', '-webkit-box', '-ms-flexbox'].includes(displayvalue)){`

Comment: The problem is that `(displayvalue == "flex" || "-webkit-box" || "-ms-flexbox")` is equivalent to `(displayvalue == "flex")||("-webkit-box")||("-ms-flexbox")` which is equal to `?? || true || true` == `true` (?? is either true or false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
if (displayvalue == "flex" || displayvalue ==  "-webkit-box" || displayvalue ==  "-ms-flexbox"){
// do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Works perfectly! What happens if it's not written like you've shown? Why does the condition equal TRUE?

Comment: Because you list a value instead of a check after the OR. And a value like "i'm a string" is always TRUE, since it's, well, a value and not nothing :)

Comment: Oh okay I see. Many thanks! too bad my upvote doesn't count.